# Coloring the line in ListLinePlot according to a rule

Tags: plotting, color

Mathematica noob here. So I have a list of values (**lvalues**) which are real numbers, some positive, some negative. I want to use ListLinePlot to plot them, but I want the **line** to become red when goes to the negative values (meaning, the line is below the x-axis), and blue when it's positive (the line is above the x-axis).
I did some little research here, but I found some solutions for coloring the points. A code (modified to my case) I found was

```
ListLinePlot[MapAt[Style[#, If[# > 0, Blue, Red]] &, {All}]@lvalues
```

The problem with this is that it is just color of the points, not the line itself, so I got the blue and red points, but the line still is a single color. Is there a way to color just the line (not the points) when it comes to ListLinePlot? (The **lvalues** come from experimental data and can't be reproduced by a function) Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
lvalues = {1, 1, 2, 3, -5, 8, -4, 8}
ListLinePlot[lvalues, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red,Blue}, MeshStyle -> Transparent]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Using `RegionFunction`:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lvalues = {1, 1, 2, 3, -5, 8, -4, 8};
if = Interpolation[lvalues, InterpolationOrder -> 1]

Show[
 Plot[if[x], {x, 0, Length@lvalues}
  , PlotRange -> {Min@lvalues, Max@lvalues}
  , PlotStyle -> Blue
  , RegionFunction -> (#2 > 0 &)
  ],
 Plot[if[x], {x, 0, Length@lvalues}
  , PlotRange -> {Min@lvalues, Max@lvalues}
  , PlotStyle -> Red
  , RegionFunction -> (#2 < 0 &)
  ]
 ]
```

---

[image]